# Is it true that $(A, \mathcal F_A,\mathbb P(.|A))$ is a probability space.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $A\in \mathcal F$ s.t. $\mathbb P(A)>0$. In an exercise I have, I need to prove that $(A, \mathcal F_A, \mathbb P(.|A))$ is a probability space where $\mathbb P(C\mid A)=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap C)}{\mathbb P(A)}$ and $\mathcal F_A=\{B\cap A\mid B\in \mathcal F\}$. Is it really true ?

- I agree that $\mathcal F_A$ is a $\sigma -$agebra on $A$.
- I agree that $\mathbb Q(C)=\frac{\mathbb P(C)}{\mathbb P(A)}$ for $C\in \mathcal F_A$ is a measure.

But for me $\mathbb P(.|A)$ is a measure on $\Omega $, and $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P(.|A))$ is a probability measure, but $(A,\mathcal F_A,\mathbb P(.|A))$ is not. So, what is $\mathbb P(.|A)$ for $(A,\mathcal F_A)$ ? or what represent the probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P(.|A))$ for $(A,\mathcal F_A, \mathbb Q)$ ?

Comment: Obviously they mean $P(\;{\cdot}\mid A)$ _restricted to_  $\mathcal F_A$ -- which is exactly the thing you want to call $Q$ instead.

Comment: Note also that you could equally say $\mathcal F_A = \{ B\in\mathcal F \mid B\subseteq A\}$, which gives the same result as your definition because $\mathcal F$ is an algebra and therefore closed under intersection.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: But $\mathbb P(\cdot |A)$ can eat in $\mathcal F$, not only $\mathcal F_A$... that a bit my problem...

Comment: Why is that a _problem_? Just ignore what it does to inputs outside of $\mathcal F_A$.

Comment: What you need to have a probability measure on $\mathcal F_A$ is to explain how to find the probability of an arbitrary element of $\mathcal F_A$. Writing "$P(\;{\cdot}\mid A)$" supplies such an explanation clearly and succinctly. That there are also other things it might explain should not be a problem.